# How to redirect people after signin using NextAuth based on specific condition

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am trying to redirect people to the dashboard "/" if the accounComplete is true, otherwise to `profile/edit/${session.user.id}`. I am using the SignIn callback to check if the condition is truthy. The redirection works, but when I try to access the session with useSession() from the navbar, I get undefined and then null.

This is my authOptions:

```
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.role = token.role;
      return session;
    },
    async signIn({ user }) {
      const currentUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: user.id,
        },
      });

      if (currentUser?.accountComplete === false) {
        return `profile/edit/${currentUser?.id}`;
      }

      return "/";
    },
  },
```

If I am doing something wrong, please let me know how to handle redirection after successful login based on a specific condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are using return in nextauth for wrong purpose.

The return is meant to return data not redirect user.

```
if (comparePasswords) {
          return {
            id: user.id,
            email: user.email,
          };
        }
 return null;
```

The thing that you return you can access from session

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

// Session interface from next-auth you don't need to create it just example what next auth expects
interface Session {
  expires: string;
  user?: {
   email?: string;
   image?: string;
   name?: string;
  }
}
// If login success session can't be null.
const { data: session } = useSession();
```

For redirection you should redirect on login page, based on session results or better yet create auth-guard for redirection logic if appropriate.